# Pythontex and the g-brief address field

Tags: pdftex, letters, pythontex

I calculate some coordinates to include a cut out of a PDF (eStamps) via python. My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[
    ngerman,    % deutsch-neu
    %russian,   % russisch
    %english,   % english
    11pt,       % Schriftgröße 11pt=Std
    a4paper,    % DIN A4
    oneside,    % Einseitig
    utf8,       % Dateikodierung
    ]
{g-brief}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % dummytext
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage[makestderr]{pythontex}

\begin{pycode}
import math

def gen_incl_cmd(zeilen, spalten, n, path):
    xLftOff = 22.5
    xRgtOff = 27.45
    yTopOff = 14.1
    yBtmOff = 19.0

    xDINA4 = 210.0
    yDINA4 = 297.0

    xLftStamp = 2.75
    xRgtStamp = 7.5
    yTopStamp = 11
    yBtmStamp = 21.5

    xSpacing = (xDINA4 - xLftOff - xRgtOff) / spalten
    ySpacing = (yDINA4 - yTopOff - yBtmOff) / zeilen

    zeile  = math.floor( (n-1) / spalten )
    spalte = (n-1) % spalten

    if zeile > zeilen:
        print('\\fbox{\\parbox[c]{1.7cm}{OUT OF\\\\STAMPS}}')
    else:
        top     = yTopOff + zeile  * ySpacing + yTopStamp
        left    = xLftOff + spalte * xSpacing + xLftStamp

        right   = xDINA4 - (left + xSpacing) + xRgtStamp
        bottom  = yDINA4 - (top + ySpacing)  + yBtmStamp
        print('\\includegraphics[trim={0}mm {1}mm {2}mm {3}mm, clip]{{{4}}}'.format(left, bottom, right, top, path))    # trim=left bottom right top
\end{pycode}

\newcommand{\ePostMarke}[4]{
    \parpic[r]{
        \pyc{gen_incl_cmd(#1, #2, #3, '#4')}
    }
}

\Name           {name}
\Strasse        {street}
\Ort            {zip city}

\Unterschrift   {\vspace{-1.7cm}signiture}

\Postvermerk    {}      % Einschreiben, etc.
\Adresse        {
                %\ePostMarke{8}{4}{5}{C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/LaTeX/Vorlagen/Briefe/TestPrint}
                addr of recipient\\
                its street\\
                zip and city\\
                }
\Betreff        {subject}
\Datum          {\today}
\Anrede         {adress}
\Gruss          {greets}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{g-brief}
\blindtext

\ePostMarke{8}{4}{10}{C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/LaTeX/Vorlagen/Briefe/TestPrint}~\\
\ePostMarke{8}{4}{40}{C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/LaTeX/Vorlagen/Briefe/TestPrint}~\\

\pyc{gen_incl_cmd(8,4,10,'C:/Users/Lenny/Documents/LaTeX/Vorlagen/Briefe/TestPrint')}

\blindtext
\end{g-brief}
\end{document}
```

The code doesent work as long as the first line in `\Adresse` is not commented out. Even the eStamp includes in the text dont work.

But if `\Adresse` is free from `\ePostMarke` command every include works fine. Pythontex complains like this:

```
Prozess gestartet: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/pythontex.bat" "D:\Downloads\tex\brief\BRIEF VORLAGE.tex"

This is PythonTeX 0.14

* PythonTeX warning
    Unknown option ""

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\program files\miktex 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py", line 62, in <module> pythontex.main() File "C:\program files\miktex 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex2.py", line 2626, in main load_code_get_settings(data, temp_data) File "C:\program files\miktex 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex2.py", line 475, in load_code_get_settings key, val = line.split('=', 1) ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

and my build chain is

```
"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex" ?ame" -parse-first-line -shell-escape -enable-write18 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode | "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/pythontex.bat" ?ame" | "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex" ?ame"  -parse-first-line -shell-escape -enable-write18 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode | txs:///view-pdf-internal --embedded
```

As you see I'm on Win7 x64, MiKTeX 2.9 (x64).

I am looking forward for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the interaction between `pythontex` and `g-brief`. The `g-brief` environment is causing code to be written to the `pythontex` temp file after `pythontex` has already treated the document as complete. The error is due to `pythontex` trying to parse the code as options when it is actually code.

If you insert a `\clearpage` after the end of the `g-brief` environment, everything should work. I've opened an [issue for this](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/68), so that the issue can be fixed in a future `pythontex` release.

Comment: perfect `\clearpage` worked. thank you!